# Faster way to get maximum date for specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I've been designing a shopping "system" for some non-profit organisations using Google Sheets. I have a problem that I solved, however I am feeling there is an easier and faster way to do it.

To simplify, I have a sheet with `PRICES`, which looks like following:

```
(A)Code    (B)Date        (C)Price
AA1        01/08/2017     50.00
BB1        01/08/2017     40.00
AA1        12/08/2017     60.00
```

Then we have `SALES` sheet:

```
(A)SalesId    (B)Date         (C)Code     (D)Price
001           05/08/2017      AA1         50.00
002           10/08/2017      BB1         40.00
003           13/08/2017      AA1         60.00
```

The above is how the sales spreadsheet should look like. What I'm trying to achieve:

To get the latest price of particular item before or on date of the order.

At the moment for each row in sales sheet I'm using QUERY, which is very slow.
This is my formula for second row in my sales sheet

```
=QUERY(Prices!A:C, "SELECT D WHERE A='" & $C2 & "' AND B <= DATE""" & TEXT($B2, "yyyy-mm-dd") & """ ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Problem is, executing QUERY for each row makes the spreadsheet quite slow. I keep thinking if there is a better way to get the maximum date before order date and take the corresponding price?

Comment: I want to be able to track the price changes, without typing the price into the order every time.

Comment: Or is it an overkill, the problem is that they want to change prices every now and then. Should I make them type the item prices then? Also it allows me to select max date and its price to show current "status" of the product, versus previous price changes.. but it might be too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I advocate  structural data entry changes for the long run, this *might* be a efficient solution to give you time to change the basic data entry structure:

D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2,IF(C2=Prices!$A$2:$A$4,Prices!$B$2:$C$4),2,1))
```

Still needs to be drag filled down.

Comment: Shows that it did not find the value in VLOOKUP evaluation. Example, the order is on 7th Aug, but the latest price for the item is 1st Aug

Comment: I have yes, does it have something to do with how dates are passed and represented. I hardcoded it like that: ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("07/08/2017", IF(), 2, FALSE)) but it says  that it did not find the value in the evaluation. Which is strange, because I hardcoded values that are definitely in the other sheet

Comment: Okay it works now, my silly mistakes, it's faster than QUERY, though still takes 5 min to update the sheet. Need to think about better approach here but thank you for all your help

Comment: I only have like 50 rows but I apply the formula to about 1000, as I can't count on people knowing how to reapply formulas and unfortunately when you click "Add 1000 rows" it doesn't copy the formulas. It took about 5-6 minutes - my guess is that everything is evaluated even for empty rows :/